# Spring MVC syntactically incorrect request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating a web application using Spring MVC, but all my POST request result in "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect". As an example, this is a search form:

```
<form id="projectsForm" action="#" th:action="@{/projects}" th:object="${projectsForm}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{page}" />

<div id="search">
    <select id="expert" th:field="*{expert}">
        <option value="">(select expert)</option>
        <option th:each="expert : ${experts}"
                th:value="${expert.id}"
                th:text="${expert.firstName + ' ' + expert.lastName}"></option>
    </select>
    <select id="company" th:field="*{company}">
        <option value="">(select company)</option>
        <option th:each="company : ${companies}"
                th:value="${company.id}"
                th:text="${company.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="query" th:field="*{query}" />
    <button class="search" onclick="firstPage()">Search</button>
    <button class="empty" onclick="empty()">Erase</button>
</div>
```

The form object class looks like this:

```
public class ProjectsForm {

    private Expert expert;
    private Company company;
    private String query;
    private Integer page = 0;
    private Integer pages;

    public Expert getExpert() {
        return expert;
    }

    public void setExpert(Expert expert) {
        this.expert = expert;
    }

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public Integer getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(Integer pages) {
        if (pages > 0 && page >= pages) {
            page = pages - 1;
        }
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

And this is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/projects", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String projectsPost(@ModelAttribute("projectsForm") ProjectsForm projectsForm, ModelMap model) {
    sessionBean.setProjectsForm(projectsForm);
    Page<Project> projectPage = projectService.findAll(projectsForm.getPage(), ProjectController.PAGESIZE, projectsForm.getExpert(), projectsForm.getCompany(), projectsForm.getQuery());
    List<Project> projects = projectPage.getContent();
    model.addAttribute("projects", projects);
    projectsForm.setPage(projectPage.getNumber());
    projectsForm.setPages(projectPage.getTotalPages());
    model.addAttribute("projectsForm", projectsForm);
    return "projects";
}
```

Chrome tells me the form data look like this:

```
page=0&expert=&company=&query=
```

Is there an obvious error, or is there any way I can diagnose this problem? Adding log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=DEBUG to log4j.properties didn't give me any more information. What also puzzles me is that the exact same code worked fine in a Spring Boot jar application.

Comment: can you tell us why you are writing like th:action="@{/projects}" th:object="${projectsForm}" especially with @symbol at begining but in controller url mapping is there only for /projects

Comment: Do you have `Converter`s or `PropertyEditor`s to convert the values (how is the number from the select (company and expert) converted to an actual instance of those classes/? Judging by what the form data is (according to your Chrome that is), you have nothing selected or entered.

Comment: show `firstPage()` i.e. how you submit form, and have you added `ProjectsForm` instance in GET handler?

Comment: @Karibasappa. He writes this because he is using Thymeleaf as the TemplateEngine. The syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: oh okie...i am not aware of Thymeleaf..any advantage of using it?

Comment: Implementing the necessary converters solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Try setting `org.springframework.http`, `org.apache.httpcomponents` and `org.apache.http` logging to DEBUG.